# Is there a good question and answer plugin for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to implement a 'stackoverflow' type answer and question for my wordpress blog.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How is this programming-related? I'd suggest migrating to SuperUser.

Answer (score 5):

If you aim to provide a service such as this you should be able to code it yourself.
Check the following sites for information on where to start:

- [Writing a Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)
- [WP Tutorial: Your First WP
  Plugin](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2006/03/04/wp-tutorial-your-first-wp-plugin/)
- [How to Write a WordPress Plugin – Introduction](http://www.devlounge.net/articles/how-to-write-a-wordpress-plugin-introduction)
- [Create a Custom WordPress Plugin From Scratch](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/creating-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch/)
- [Anatomy of a WordPress Plugin](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/anatomy-of-a-wordpress-plugin/)

If, by some reason you want to use a pre-written plugin I found one called [UnAnswered](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/unasked-questions-and-answers-plugin/) that, according to the maker allows you to have a similar functionality to the one you are after. You should be able to customize it to your needs and likes.

Answer (score 1):

I just released a plugin + theme that does the job : http://wp-answers.com/

Answer (score 1):

I am using AnsPress, http://wordpress.org/plugins/anspress

Demo: http://open-wp.com/

This plugin is actively developed and have many cool features. I use this plugin on my site and its very easy.
I also love the support by its developer, he respond very fast and try to solve any issue I have.

Answer (score 0):

I have this plugin if you are interested..

http://www.sabaidiscuss.com/

demo here: http://demo.sabaidiscuss.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sabai-Discuss](http://www.sabaidiscuss.com/) plugin by onokazu. I like it.

Also there is [Wpmu-dev's Q&A](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin/) Plugin which is quite similar.